# Cart item discount based on specific product variation in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, coupon, discount

I’ve, on my DIY sell store, a product named ‘Reusable wet’ which come in different patterns and different packages.

- 5 Reusable wet cost €10
- 10 Reusable wet cost €18

Since they are a lot of different patterns, the customer could want 10 wet, but take two different packages of 5, to get two different patterns. Unfortunately, it would cost him 2 more euros, and I want to avoid this situation.

How could I detect this behaviour, and more precisely, where should I hook that?

I thought of putting it in the cart preview, maybe automatically add a reduction coupon if I detect these packages, but I’m not sure if it’s the most efficient way of doing it.

Any suggestions would help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your product named "Reusable wet" **is a variable product** with multiple variations based on some product attributes.

So in your case, **the discount can be applied in 2 different ways**.

> But first you will need to define the related product attribute **SLUG** that is involved in  "Reusable wet" quantity pack and the related term **NAME** value for the "pack of 5" in the code.
>
> **If this seetings are not done in the right way, the code will not work.**

1) **Changing related item prices** *(the best way)*:

> Here we set a discounted unit price of `9` *(`18 / 2 = 9`)* when there is 2 related items or more in cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_set_discounted_price', 30, 1 );
function conditionally_set_discounted_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // HERE your product attribute slug for "Reusable wet" (without "pa_")
    $product_attr = 'reusable-wet';
    $product_attr = 'color';

    // HERE set the corresponding (value) term NAME for "5 Reusable wet"
    $term_slug = '5 reusable wet';
    $term_slug = 'Black';

    // HERE set the discounted price for each cart item with "5 Reusable wet" when they are 2 or more
    $discounted_price = 9; // (18 / 2 = 9)

    $five_rw_count = 0; // Initializing variable

    // 1st Loop: count cart items with "5 Reusable wet"
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_attribute( $product_attr ) == $term_slug ){
            $five_rw_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    // Continue if there is at least 2 units of "5 Reusable wet"
    if( $five_rw_count < 2 ) return; // Exit

    // 2nd Loop: set the discounted price for cart items with "5 Reusable wet"
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_attribute( $product_attr ) == $term_slug ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($discounted_price); // Set the discounted price
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

---

2) **The coupon way** *(not very convenient for many logical reasons)*:

> Here you will have to set the coupon code. This coupon settings should be like:
>
> [image]
>
> Where you will set all related product variations in the "products" field.

Once done you will set the coupon name (in lowercase) in the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_auto_add_coupon', 30, 1 );
function conditionally_auto_add_coupon( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') ) return; // Exit

    // HERE your product attribute slug for "Reusable wet" (without "pa_")
    $product_attr = 'reusable-wet';

    // HERE set the corresponding (value) term NAME for "5 Reusable wet"
    $term_slug = '5 reusable wet';

    // HERE set the coupon code (in lowercase)
    $coupon_code = 'multiplefive';

    $five_rw_count = 0; // Initializing variable

    // 1st Loop: count cart items with "5 Reusable wet"
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_attribute( $product_attr ) == $term_slug ){
            $five_rw_count++; // Increasing count
        }
    }

    // Apply the coupon if there is at least 2 units of "5 Reusable wet"
    if ( ! $cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) && $five_rw_count >= 2 ) {
        $cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );  
    } 
    // Remove the coupon if there is at less than 2 units of "5 Reusable wet"
    elseif  ( $cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) && $five_rw_count < 2 ) {
        $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

---

Related: [Auto apply or remove a coupon in Woocommerce cart for a specific product id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738432/auto-apply-or-remove-a-coupon-in-woocommerce-cart-for-a-specific-product-id/49740020#49740020)

Comment: Went for the first solution except that I filtered on the categoryId and the price. Many thanks! :)

Comment: Is there a way to capture specific variations on all products. So if I have a variation called "Boxed" and multiple sizes of "Boxed" the coupon will apply to all variations containing the word "Boxed" but not "Unboxed"